# Json Column in delta table databricks

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a view in databricks and in one column the content is a json, example:

```
[{"ECID":100017056,"FIRST_NAME":"Ioannis","LAST_NAME":"CHATZIZYRLIS","TITLE":"Mr","GENDER":"M","DATE_OF_BIRTH":"1995-04-14","PLACE_OF_BIRTH":"Greece","COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH":"GR","NATIONALITY":"GR","RESIDENCE":"GR","ADDRESS":[{"TYPE":1,"STREET_1":"Gizi 6","CITY":"Agios Doe","POSTAL_CODE":"111 34","COUNTRY":"GR","MOBILE":"0000000","EMAIL":" "}]}]
```

I want to retrieve the content of that column so that I can post it to an api.

I tried loading it in a dataframe and then flatting it and various other options but each time I get it back as below, having it encapsulated in [Row()]

```
[Row(ECID=100016583, CID=None, FIRST_NAME='test', LAST_NAME='test', TITLE='Ms', GENDER='F', DATE_OF_BIRTH=datetime.date(1989, 10, 22), PLACE_OF_BIRTH='test', COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH='RS', NATIONALITY='RS', RESIDENCE='RS', AGENCY_ID=None, ADDRESS=[Row(TYPE=1, STREET_1='test 6', STREET_2=None, STREET_3=None, CITY='test', POSTAL_CODE='12226', COUNTRY='RS', PHONE=None, MOBILE='1111111', EMAIL='test@yahoo.com')], PASSPORT=[Row(DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID=1, DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT', NUMBER='test', FIRST_NAME='test', LAST_NAME='test', ISSUE_COUNTRY='RS', ISSUE_CITY='test', ISSUE_DATE=datetime.date(2019, 10, 24), EXPIRATION_DATE=datetime.date(2029, 10, 24), PRIMARY=True)], VISAS=[Row(VISA_NAME_ID='Mandatory; Internal MXP identifier of Visa name. -Probably mapping', VISA_NAME='German Embassy', VISA_NUMBER='test', VISA_ISSUED_CITY_NAME='test', VISA_ISSUED_COUNTRY='RS', VISA_ISSUED_DATE=datetime.date(2021, 12, 28), VISA_EXPIRATION_DATE=datetime.date(2023, 1, 2))])]
```

How can I retrieve it so that I can get it in the correct format so that I can post it to the api?

Answer (score 1):

When you do all necessary transformations and collect the data to driver node, then you can just call the `.asDict` on the row object to get Python dict representation of that row

```py
df = ... # transform
data = [r[0].asDict() for r in df.collect()]
```

- The `for r in df.collect()` iterates over the rows of the dataframe
- `r[0]` gives you a struct column represented as `Row` object
- `.asDict` converts it into Python dictionary

P.S. If you have a lot of data to send, then you may consider using the Pandas UDF instead so you can call API in parallel from all executors

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.rdd.flatmap` to get information extracted from the `Row`.

**`Example:`**

```
json = """[{"ECID":100017056,"FIRST_NAME":"Ioannis","LAST_NAME":"CHATZIZYRLIS","TITLE":"Mr","GENDER":"M","DATE_OF_BIRTH":"1995-04-14","PLACE_OF_BIRTH":"Greece","COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH":"GR","NATIONALITY":"GR","RESIDENCE":"GR"}]"""
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json]), multiLine=True)
print(df.columns)
#['COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH', 'DATE_OF_BIRTH', 'ECID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'GENDER', 'LAST_NAME', 'NATIONALITY', 'PLACE_OF_BIRTH', 'RESIDENCE', 'TITLE']
print(df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
#['GR', '1995-04-14', 100017056, 'Ioannis', 'M', 'CHATZIZYRLIS', 'GR', 'Greece', 'GR', 'Mr']
```